# npm start showing error during execution

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

> npm : npm ERR! path C:\Users\sanjeev\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\mvc_ng-2\package.json At line:1 char:1
>   + npm start
>   + ~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm ERR! path C...-2\package.json:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   npm   ERR!   code  ENOENT
>
> npm   ERR!   errno  -4058
>
> npm   ERR!   syscall  open
>
> npm   ERR!   enoent  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\sanjeev\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\mvc_ng-2\package.json'
>
> npm   ERR!   enoent  This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm   ERR!   enoent  and is related to npm not being able to find a
>   file.
>
> npm   ERR!   enoent
>
> npm   ERR!  A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm  ERR!
>        C:\Users\sanjeev\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-05-22T09_24_43_498Z-debug.log

Can someone please tell me what the error is why it is stopping it from running

Comment: The error is saying that `no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sanjeev\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\mvc_ng-2\package.json'`. It is so clear. Node can't find your package.json file.

Comment: @ulubeyn but it is present there

Comment: Can you post your package.json file?